# Did the following steps have sense in securing my login process?

Tags: php, security, authentication, system

Hello i want to build a nice log in system and i am thinking in that steps hope you can told me if this is really efficient against hackers and crackers :)

1- In my login form each time page loaded i will generate these SESSION variables

```
SESSION1 = random()
SESSION2 = random()
SESSION3 = random()
SESSION4 = time()
SESSIONHASHKEY = array(){[SESSION1 digits]};
SESSIONRESULT = hash(Concatenation of caracters at position  situated inside the SESSIONHASHKEY array from the SESSION2);
Set the name of the button of the login to the SESSION3 number)
```

2- Put a file named auth.php between my login form (where user enter username and password) and my authentication page(where my code will validate if username and password are correct)

```
if !isset SESSION1 redirect login page
if !isset SESSION2 redirect login page
if !isset SESSION3 redirect login page
if !isset SESSION4 redirect login page

if SESSION1 digits array != SESSIONHASHKEY redirect loginpage
if MD5(concatenation of caracters at position situated inside the SESSIONHASHKEY) != SESSIONRESULT redirect loginpage

if !isset loginbutton_{SHA256(MD5(SHA256(MD5(SHA256(SESSION3)))))} redirect login page
if (time() - SESSION4) >10 redirect loginpage
```

if the test is passed successfully i will do a redirect to the authenticating page passing username and password within a session

This is my scenario so i hope you can help me in defining the security level of look like process :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you're getting no benefit from all the added complexity of introducing an intemediary page. Add to that that you're hashing a hash of a hash of a hash of a hash (dramatically increasing the likelyhood of duplicate hashes) and significantly increasing the handling time of a login.

Unless you have a specific reason to even try and do anything so unnecessarily complex, don't try to reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of simple and as-secure (if not much more so) than this approach to be found on the web.

This article has some good practices for building a secure login:
[PHP Secure Login Tips And Tricks](http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-secure-login-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: My points still stand, regardless of who accesses that page or when :)

Comment: Thank you for replying and let me read the post you have told me about and let me know too much infos :)

But What i want to say that my hashing process goes on just to create an identifier to name the button that will do the login it is not hashing for user name and password and so on ,so i can assure that the user doesn't access my intermediate page from else than my login form

then my intermediate page is here just really to fake the real authentication page.

So i am thinking to make the login process like a maze :)

Plz notify me where is really the weakness in my scenario

Best Regards

Comment: I want to ask about a new idea :)

it is about making a fake control panel and after the third fault login try i let the person that try to login go into the fake page and inside this control panel i will have limited access to the db .just reading and i will let buttons not functioning at all like if you let a thief enter to a room which every object within is just a picture on the wall seems being is a real object :)

So any track inside it is logged and fake message of saving data are offered without any changement in the database :)

Please let me know did this is a foolish idea :)?

Comment: I fail to see the point. Why not just block the user after too many failed attempts? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle